# Is there a package or utility in R that lets you map and fill each U.S. state by an image rather than a color?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm conceptualizing a map I will be attempting shortly, and wanted to do a fill = factor(image.) type of operation within either ggmap, ggplot2, or some other mapping package in R, so that the ultimately map looks analogous to [this](http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/mt/assets/business/tumblr_mmxqdtoGLu1rasnq9o1_1280.jpg) map I found online. Any ideas where I can start?